# Alfresco boost results from site

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, alfresco

I'm trying to boost results from a particular Alfresco site compared to others.
I've written the following query but it's not working properly :

```
(((TAG:term or cm:name:term OR cm:title:term )^8 OR (cm:description:term )^6) AND PATH:'/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:Pub/cm:documentLibrary//*')^8    
OR     
(((TAG:term or cm:name:term OR cm:title:term )^4 OR (cm:description:term )^2) AND -PATH:'/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:Pub/cm:documentLibrary//*')
```

The result is overall correct but the results from Pub aren't the first ones in the list.

Is there a way to achieve that ?

Comment: Cool, didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

^8 on the first part query part was just not enough. Putting a huge value like 100 makes it work perfectly !